# Unable to .Sendkeys with Date value in Angular input textbox

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, nunit, sendkeys

I am trying to send a date to a input textbox of an Anuglar application. The text box only accepts date format. I tried declaring the date as an int or a Date and then adding an empty string at the end, but it did not work. .Click() methods works on this object.

```
   int enterdate = 01012016;
   PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver).SendKeys(enterdate + "");

   DateTime iDate;
   iDate = DateAndTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
   PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver).SendKeys(iDate + "");
```

in both cases I get `ElementNotInteractableException`

```
<input type="text" id="ev_dateofevent" ng-keypress="allowDigit($event);" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-date ng-touched" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="fieldValueObj" is-open="isOpenCalendar" maxlength="10" ng-blur="datechange(field,id,datetitle);" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-disabled="datereadonly" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

Comment: Assuming you know selenium. try Click on that input element and then try send-keys. it will work. Let me know if you want me to write code in a comment.

Comment: @KrunalPatel If you have an answer, post it as an answer. Answers in comments are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `input` value with Javascript instead of `SendKeys`. This serves as a workaround for many JS module elements that do not accept traditional Selenium interactions.

```
var input = PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver);
Iwebdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'dateValueHere')", input);
```

Updated with a C# instead of protractor example:

```
// declare JS executor -- use your webdriver instance for driver
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

var input = PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver);

js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'dateValueHere')", input);
```

Another alternative to try, if you do not like a JS approach, could be performing a click on the element to bring it into focus before sending keys.

```
int enterdate = 01012016;

// click the input field
PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver).Click();

// send keys to the field
PageObjectsLocators.locate_Date_textfield(Iwebdriver).SendKeys(enterdate + "");
```

Comment: Could you share the assembly name(if needed) and the syntax for creating a javascript driver? I don't usually combine javascript with C#.

Comment: Based on your protractor tag, I assumed you wanted protractor syntax rather than C#. I have updated my example with some C# code instead. The syntax is slightly different -- in C#, you have to cast your driver to a JS executor, and call ExecuteScript through the executor rather than the driver itself.

Comment: .setAttribute('value',...) is not present in the DOM. Please look the tag i posted in the original post. I tried placeholder and it did not work.

Comment: This issue seems to be with the locator -- `//input[@type='text' and @placeholder='MM/dd/yyyy']` should locate the element. However, I cannot guarantee this, because I cannot see the rest of the HTML on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

so I had to combine 14 apps under 1 framework, and test to be executed in winodws/mac/linux. So the only method that sends keys correctly across all platforms/apps is this ugly code:

```
sendKeys: async ($element, keyCode = "") => {

        await $element.clear();
        await $element.click();
        await $element.sendKeys("X");
        await $element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);

        let value = await $element.getAttribute("value");
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            await $element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
        }
        await $element.sendKeys(keyCode)
    }
```

I couldn't come up with anything better than this

Comment: `.sendKeys` always gives `ElementNotInteractableException.`  For additional information, you may review the `input` tag i posted with the question.  `.Click()` works. `.Clear()` does not. it's a vendor application, so i don't have much control over the source code.